# Extract high and lows on monthly basis from Excel dataset

Tags: excel

I am trying to extract the highs and lows for each month from a set of daily high, low, close data on a stock price in Excel over several years. How would I go about doing it, i have attached an image of a spreadsheet showing my attempt.

[image]

Comment: You did not attach a spreadsheet

Comment: I couldnt but I have attached a picture insted, should be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you came up with looks like you are on the right track, but I would change to this:

```
= MAX(IF((MONTH($B$2:$B$100)=J2)*(YEAR($B$2:$B$100)=I2),$C$2:$C$100))
```

And then drag this formula down as far as necessary.

(Similarly, to find the minimum for each month, just replace `MAX` in the above equation with `MIN`.)

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula rather than just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also note you should include your entire data in this formula, not just to the end of January. In this example I took it down to the 100th row, but you will need to adjust that based on where ever your data ends.

Or if you are using Pivot Tables, @QHarr's solution will work also.

---

**EDIT**

As requested, here is what is going on in this formula:

Both `(MONTH($B$2:$B$100)=J2)` and `(YEAR($B$2:$B$100)=I2)` return vertical arrays (of the same size) of `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`'s. When you multiply them together, you get an array of 1's and 0's. (The indices of this output array will equal 1 where the corresponding indices of the input array were both equal to `TRUE`.) You are not actually multiplying the `MONTH` and `YEAR` together. This would be pointless because for example for February of 2017 you would get a value of 4034 which is meaningless.

Simple example of multiplying two logical arrays together: `{TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}*{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE}` would return `{1;0;0}`. You might expect that it should return `{TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}` but when multiplying two logical arrays, it automatically converts to an array of 1's and 0's. However, this isn't an issue because the `IF` statement will handle an array of 1's and 0's the same way it would handle an array of `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`'s so there is no need to convert it back to logical values.

The reason `AND` doesn't work is because `AND` always returns a *single* result (not an array). For example, `AND({TRUE;TRUE;FALSE},{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE})` would simply return `FALSE`. Because of this, `AND` is typically not very useful in array formulas since it, well, doesn't return arrays haha.

---

As far as returning +1, -1, or 0 depending on how it compared to the previous month, this is fairly easy to accomplish.

Since the output is in `K` column, I'll base it off of that.

In cell `L2`, type the formula (and drag down as necessary):

```
= IF(K2>K1,"+1",IF(K2<K1,"-1","0"))
```

This formula works fine *unless* you insert rows, then it may screw up the formula, which is why I usually prefer to do something like this below. (It adds a bit more to the formula, but is "safer"):

```
= IF(K2>INDEX(K:K,ROW()-1),"+1",IF(K2<INDEX(K:K,ROW()-1),"-1","0"))
```

You'll notice that these formulas are identical except that in the formula above, `K1` was replaced with `INDEX(K:K,ROW()-1)`. The issue with just typing `K1` is that, if a row is inserted between the first and second row, the reference to `K1` won't change, even though, you want it to actually increase to `K2`. This is solved with `INDEX(K:K,ROW()-1)` which always just references the cell in the `K` column directly above it, even if rows are inserted in the sheet.

Comment: Thanks very much for that elegant formula that does exactly what I wanted. I am trying to understand how it works but I am slightly confused? Does the * in the array formula actually mean multiple the month and year together (i:e J2 and I2) or is it just a condition? Also I am interested in an array which would go through each row in turn and output +1 if the current high was above the high of the previous month, -1 if the low was below the low of the previous month and 0 otherwise. Would be really grateful if you could help me on that one also?

Comment: @pvwhite01 See my post again, I edited my answer to address your questions here.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense now, I understand why the multiplication is used so that 1 will be produced only if both conditions are satisfied and zero otherwise. In looking at array formulas and tutorials on the web that has never been explained to me so much appreciated. I should have been clearer on the second part of my question. The formula needs to look through the daily data row by row and output +1 if the daily high is above the daily high of the previous month, -1 if the daily low is below the daily low of the previous month and 0 otherwise. Thanks again.

Comment: @pvwhite01 That would be the same formula, just replace all instances of `K` in that formula with `D` (because `D` column is the daily high column).

Comment: Doesn't that formula just look at the current high and compare it to the high of the previous day? I'm looking for a formula that would output +1 if the current high was above the high of the previous month. So in the scan above say for row 20 the daily high is 1089.38. It would need to output +1 only if that value was above the high value of the previous month (the January high of 1150.45 in row 11) otherwise 0. I've been trying for the last few hours and can't get seem to anywhere? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

why not just use a pivottable and change the pivot field aggregate method to maximum or minimum for High and Low fields.

Here is an example image (forgive the use of a Mac!) of adding the fields
[image: Image of adding fields]

And result

[image: Example resultant fields]

You don't have to double up on Max and Min for each field. I just wanted to show it was possible.